# Export data from MATLAB to use in gnuplot

Tags: matlab, gnuplot

I want to export data from MATLAB so that I can use it in gnuplot. For example:

```
>> a=[1 2 3 4];
>> b=[5 6 7 8];
>> c=[9 10 11];
>> d=[12 13 14];
```

I want to plot(a,b) and plot(c,d). How can I write all these variables in one file in four columns and how to use them in gnuplot?

Comment: See [MATLAB's documentation for Data Import and Export](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-import-and-export.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For vectors of same length

you can simply put the vectors into a matrix with the transposed vectors as columns and save the matrix in ASCII format:

```
out = [a' b' c' d'];
save( 'myfile.txt', 'out', '-ASCII' );
```

In gnuplot you plot with:

```
plot 'myfile.txt' u 1:2, '' u 3:4
```

#### For vectors of different length

as in your example I would recommend to put the data in separate files because the data is unrelated. If you still want to have everything in one file you can pad the smaller vectors with `NaN`s. Gnuplot won't complain about the `NaN`s in the text file. Then you can again build the matrix as before.

```
c(1,4)=NaN;
d(1,4)=NaN;
```

For the general case you should probably do this padding in a smarter way.